# Format the output for mailx email in tabular format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mailx

I'm trying the format the email in tabular form which is received through the Mailx command.

I'm using the following commands :

```
 1. df -h | mail -s "Disk Space" abc@gmail.com   

 2. df -lP | mail -s "Disk Space" abc@gmail.com
```

Although the above Linux command gives a proper structure on a terminal, it' not well structure in the email body. I do not want the output to be sent as an attachment.

What modification I have to do?

Any guidelines or help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Oh I recall this one. I can't remember if we wrapped the output in `<pre>...</pre>` or use `<table>`, but it is doable. Let me look at bit. The problem isn't with `mailx` it is with your mail reader reading mail in `html` format. If you look at what you get in fixed-width it will have preserved the format correctly. I'll drop a note when I find the old thread.

Comment: OK, here was one solution. create a temporary file and attach it as an attachment instead of including it in the body of the message. E.g. `df -h > dftmp; echo "disk usage" | mail -s "Disk Space" -a dftmp abc@gmail.com && rm dftmp`. If your attachment still shows as html -- then you will have to process the output and include `<pre> ... </pre>` tags or process as a table. You can also set the message encoding with, e.g. `mail -M "text/html"` if your version supports it.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your valuable input. But I would like to receive the content in the email body, how it can be done?

Comment: I would build it by using a temp file to add `<pre>` at the beginning and `</pre>` at the end. Then you can set `-M "text/html"` and it should display as preformatted text. Something like `echo "<pre>" > dftmp; df -h >> dftmp; echo "</pre>" >> dftmp; cat dftmp | mail -M "text/html" -s "Disk Space" abc@gmail.com; rm dftmp`  See if something like that won't work.